# gojs-angular unable to reproduce minimal example

Tags: angular, gojs

I am trying to replicate the below with my existing application but its giving me error.

https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-angular-basic

ERROR Error: Invalid DIV id; could not get element with id: myDiagramDiv(go.js:12)

```
DIV id; could not get element with id: myDiagramDiv
    at B (go.js:12)
    at Bi (go.js:789)
    at Fl (go.js:912)
    at InspectorComponent.ngAfterViewInit (inspector.component.ts:21)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:32327)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:32292)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:32274)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44280)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
```

Comment: "gojs": "^2.1.0-beta1",
    "gojs-angular": "^1.0.1",    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",

Comment: in this case step 1: try to console `$('#myDiagramDiv').length` is it > 0 ?

Comment: is your init function call after the div/ document ready?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed **gojs-angular-basic** and did an `ng serve`.  It worked well.  So I am unable to reproduce your inability to reproduce the example.